# How can I hide jQuery hover

Tags: jquery

I'm doing User Login and after doing I want the first form to be hidden and only the other field to be visible. Since I was browsing at first, it always sees it as *display:block*, how can I avoid this?
Can anyone help with this?

So in short, how can I hide my login panel after logging in?

Thank you advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".login-user").click(function () {
   $("#container").append('<div class="appendme">User Login Success</div>');
});

  $('#btn , .login, myAccount').mouseover(function(){ 
  if (jQuery('div').hasClass('appendme')){
  $('.login').css('display','none');
  $('.myAccount').css('display','block');
  }
    $('.login').show();
  }).mouseout(function(){     
    $('.login').hide();
  });    

});
```

```css
.login, .myAccount{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  display:none;
}
#btn{
  width:300px;
}
.appendme{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="btn">
    My Account
  </button>
  <div class="login"> 
    Login Panel
    <button class="login-user">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myAccount"> 
    <ul>
    <li>My account Edit</li>
    <li>My Wishlist</li>
    <li>My Orders</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you store/identify a logged in visitor?

Comment: After logging in, I don't want the login panel to appear when navigating my account. I just want myAccount class to appear

Comment: Correct, but how do you know when someone is logged in?

Comment: When login is pressed I just create a div and a class, for example if there is such a class then the user is logged in.

Comment: Pressing login doesn't necessarily mean that the user is logged in, right?

Comment: I know the details to, just can you help me how to hide login panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$('.login').remove();`,
but you should check how and when a user is logged in, and not make it dependable on a simply click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".login-user").click(function () {
   $("#container").append('<div class="appendme">User Login Success</div>');
   $('.login').remove();
});

  $('#btn , .login, myAccount').mouseover(function(){ 
  if (jQuery('div').hasClass('appendme')){
  $('.login').css('display','none');
  $('.myAccount').css('display','block');
  }
    $('.login').show();
  }).mouseout(function(){     
    $('.login').hide();
  });    

});
```

```css
.login, .myAccount{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  display:none;
}
#btn{
  width:300px;
}
.appendme{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="btn">
    My Account
  </button>
  <div class="login"> 
    Login Panel
    <button class="login-user">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myAccount"> 
    <ul>
    <li>My account Edit</li>
    <li>My Wishlist</li>
    <li>My Orders</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```